# apalike bibliography changes to numbers suddenly

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, apa-style

I am using natbib package in my project, which has \documentclass{report}, and I am using apalike style for my bibliography. I am currently using v2.overleaf to write my document. Everything was working so far, but now when I add any more references in my document's .bib file, the citations in my document change from author, date (I mostly used \citep(something), they change to numbers. It looks like there is a limit on the number of references.

I cannot seem to find what the problem is, but here is some info:

- I have used 48 references so far, and adding the 49th lead to this problem (I have no idea if this is related or not)
- my .bib file now has 541 lines.

I wonder if anyone has faced this problem before.

I appreciate any help guys :)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}
some text here \citep{citation48}
some other text \citep{citation49} 
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
{\footnotesize
\bibliography{library.bib}}
\end{document}
```

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Comment: Adding references to the `.bib` file shouldn't affect your document at all unless you also cite them in the document. So when you cite the 49th reference, what does the output look like? Can you edit your question to include a minimal compilable document (beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` that shows exactly how you are generating the bibliography? (No other packages should be needed in the example other than `natbib`).

Comment: Welcome, please don't feel offense, but i guess you will get a quicker solution to your problem by getting in touch with the Overleaf help team. I guess you won't be able to make us reproduce your local problem.

Comment: This is a very weird problem, the more so because the `apalike` bibliography style is only set up to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs. If you're getting numeric-style citation call-outs all of a sudden, something very odd must have happened. Without access to your code, it's unfortunately not possible to offer a definitive diagnosis. Real quick: did you check (a) that there's no additional `\bibliographystyle` instruction lurking around somewhere and (b) that the `natbib` package isn't all of a sudden being loaded with the option `numbers`?

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments, I tried to follow your instructions and  add some codes and screenshots.
I will get in touch with overleaf to ask them, no offense taken :)
there is no additional \bibliographystyle, and I do not touch natbib. the only thing I change is cite another (any) citation and boom, apalike changes to numbers!

Comment: `natbib` has a user macro `\setcitestyle{numbers}` which will change the citation style mid document. That's the only way I can reproduce the behaviour you report. Check your document to see if such a command is there.  Alternatively, can you add the 49th `.bib` file entry to your question. (See next comment).

Comment: The `natbib` documentation also says *The natbib package will automatically switch to numerical mode if any one of the \bibitem entries fails to conform to the possible author–year formats. There is no way to override this, since such an entry would cause trouble in the author–year mode.* So perhaps a mal-formed entry is the problem.

Comment: @AlanMunn I think you solved the problem! There are strangely two entries which do not conform with author-year format and reformatting them solved the problem. Thank you guys very much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `natbib` documentation states:

> The `natbib` package will automatically switch to numerical mode if any one of the `\bibitem` entries fails to conform to the possible author–year formats. There is no way to override this, since such an entry would cause trouble in the author–year mode.

It does this only after generating an error:

```
! Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

(natbib)                Press <return> to continue in numerical citation style.
```

Unfortunately, online LaTeX systems like ShareLaTeX and Overleaf do everything they can to produce some output and try to push through errors wherever they can. This problem is compounded by the fact that there is no simple way to view the error log without downloading it (last time I checked).  For example, if you have the following `.bib` file entry, namely an item with an author but no year, and you push through the error, the bibliography will be generated using the numeric system.  From your comment it seems that something of this sort is what happened.

```
@misc{Foo2018,
    Author = {Foo},
    Howpublished = {Unpublished manuscript},
    Title = {A title}}
```

Comment: That was exactly the case! I really appreciate your assistance Alan.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but can't find the problematic entry. How can I know exactly which entries are generating the problem?

Comment: @MrT77 When you run `bibtex` on the document you should see a warning in the `.blg` file that tells you which items are missing years.